# Can't run screen due to "cannot open terminal '/dev/pts/1' - please check" error

Tags: command-line, server

To learn some server management I just created a new Ubuntu 12.04 server. Since I only had a root account I created a new user with `adduser kramer65`. I then switched to that user using `su kramer65`. I now want to run screen, so I typed `screen` and hit enter, after which I'm presented with this line:

```
Cannot open your terminal '/dev/pts/1' - please check.
```

And here I'm lost. Why doesn't it open screen, and what should I do with the very helpful tip "*please check*"?

All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I ssh'ed into the machine as root, then changed to the user kramer65 with `su kramer65` and then tried to run screen, where screen can only be run by the user that logs in using ssh. So after I added kramer65 to the sudoers file with `usermod -aG sudo kramer65` I could ssh into the machine as kramer65 and run screen with a big smile.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your own answer as 'the' answer... and thanks for posting the solution! I'll be sure to evernote this into my SysAdmin tool belt :-)

Answer (score 14):

There is a way around this without resorting to adding the user (`kramer65` in this example) to the sudoers file. If you run `script /dev/null` right before attaching a screen session (or creating a new screen session), you should then be able to run your session without that error.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to work.  You can run something like `script /dev/null -c "screen ..."` to run a command inside the screen.